# golang build command returns unexpected directory layout

Tags: glide-golang

I'm attempting to compile https://github.com/xteve-project/xTeVe.
Instructions state to download sourcecode and then dependances

```
go get github.com/koron/go-ssdp
go get github.com/gorilla/websocket
go get github.com/kardianos/osext
```

following error upon running: `go get https://github.com/xteve-project/xTeVe`

```
unexpected directory layout:
        import path: _/home/pi/go/src/github.com/xteve-project/xTeVe/src/internal/authentication
        root: /home/pi/go/src
        dir: /home/pi/go/src/github.com/xteve-project/xTeVe/src/internal/authentication
        expand root: /home/pi/go
        expand dir: /home/pi/go/src/github.com/xteve-project/xTeVe/src/internal/authentication
        separator: /
```

I have go 1.13.4 installed

GOPATH is set to $HOME/go

go directory structure:

```
├── ./hello
├── ./pkg
│   └── ./pkg/linux_arm
│       └── ./pkg/linux_arm/github.com
└── ./src
    ├── ./src/github.com
    │   ├── ./src/github.com/gorilla
    │   ├── ./src/github.com/kardianos
    │   └── ./src/github.com/koron
    ├── ./src/golang.org
    │   └── ./src/golang.org/x
    └── ./src/xTeVe
        ├── ./src/xTeVe/html
        ├── ./src/xTeVe/src
        └── ./src/xTeVe/ts
```

Either it's a problem with my directory structure (likely) or the code (highly unlikely).

I've tried downloading the source code manually and placing in various directories but always seem to encounter same error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It was indeed the directory structure. Should have been the following:

```
├── ./pkg
│   └── ./pkg/linux_arm
├── ./src
│   ├── ./src/github.com
│   └── ./src/golang.org
└── ./xTeVe-master
    ├── ./xTeVe-master/html
    ├── ./xTeVe-master/src
    └── ./xTeVe-master/ts
```

So xTeve-master should be on the same level as your src direcotry. Basically run everything from the GOPATH directory.